# Detect screenshots on macOS swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5, macos-big-sur

When searching online about detecting screenshots through file metadata, I found the following way to detect a screenshot being taken with `NSMetadataQuery`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ShareZApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSMetadataQueryDelegate {
    
    let query = NSMetadataQuery()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        let center = NotificationCenter.default
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(queryUpdated(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidStartGathering, object: query)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(queryUpdated(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object: query)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(queryUpdated(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: query)
        
        query.delegate = self
        query.searchScopes = []
        query.enableUpdates()
        query.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "kMDItemIsScreenCapture = 1")
        query.start()
    }
    
    @objc func queryUpdated(notification: NSNotification) {
        print(notification)
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach is not working, and from sources online it seems macOS 10.15 did some changes detecting similar events. Is this the case here as well? Running the `xattr` command on a screenshot also displays the meta tag, so it has not been removed:
[image: screenshot meta]

Or is there another way to detect this meta tag? I am running macOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems there is an even easier way to achieve what I am trying to do, I can invoke the `/usr/sbin/screencapture` executable to create a screenshot, and using the `-i -r </path/to/target>` flags I can specify an output path.